# Zero article with countable nouns

Tags: noun, article

I came across this sentence in Wikipedia:

> Eine [Tasse](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasse) ist ein Trinkgefäß mit ***Henkel***, das vorrangig für Heißgetränke verwendet wird.

***Ein Henkel*** is a countable noun. In English, a singular countable noun usually takes an article. So it will be "with ***a*** handle". Isn't it the same in German? If so, shouldn't it be "mit ***einem*** Henkel"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can often leave the "einem"/"einen" aus, like in "Mit Schirm, Charme und Melone" (Instead of "Mit einem Schirm, Charme und einer Melone" - for 'Charme', it is still left out because it is not countable).
When the number is obvious (Henkel is singular, so it's clear that there's only one anyway), you can leave it out without problem.

Anyway, it is always correct to say "..mit einem Henkel.."

Comment: Wieso war "Mit Schirm, Charme und Melone" mit nur einem Schirm? Und für Alte, Kranke und Kinder gibt es auch Tassen mit 2 Henkeln. Auf die Einzahl kommt es m.E. nicht an. Sie und Ihre Familie können mit Auto anreisen. Ich kaufe eine Hose mit Saum.